# SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Can I call `detailViewController` methods or get attributes declared as `IBOutlets` by me in the class, from another `rootViewController` that I have created?

I have this hierarchy of `rootControlViews`:

```
[RootViewController]
    [Cell 1] -> [Cell1RootViewController] (push Cell1RootView... into the navController]
```

Only one `DetailViewController` with an `IBOutlet` declared object (and synthethised) called `object`.

I select the `[Cell 1]`, So I am now inside `Cell1RootViewController`. How can I call the `object` declared in `DetailViewController` from here?.

I have tried declaring it inside `Cell1RootViewController` and tried linking it by reference outlet with the one that is inside `DetailViewController`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `SplitViewController`, then you have a `MasterView` and a `ControllerView` (that extends/implements `TableDataSource` and `TableDelegate` protocols).

If you wanted to have several `ControllerViews` because of something, and wanted to call `MasterView` methods when inside of any `ControllView` of yours, you should have an INIT method like this:

```
- (id) initWithMasterView: (MasterView *) theMaster, ....otherOptionsYouWant{
       self = [super init]
       if (self){ 
               myMasterInstance = theMaster;
               //other initializations you want here
       }
       return self;
}
```